# Make auto titles on html using JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The code below makes the first step: add an image with a link to the home-page and an h1 with the name of the document, if there isn't an h1 already.

I used an html that references a JavaScript file in the `<head>` and has a `<h1>` tag for the title (this is one of the expectations that I want to make this because of the special characters).

```js
document.write('<a href="rpg.html"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/U%2B2190.svg/25px-U%2B2190.svg.png"></a><br>');

if (document.getElementById(titulo) != null) /*se existir um não titulo... */ {
  var nome_do_documento = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); /*colete o nome do documento */
  var titulo = nome_do_documento.replace('_', ' '); /*troque _ por um espaço */
  var titulo_pronto = titulo.replace('.html', ''); /*apague a extenção do nome */
  document.write('<h1 id="titulo">' + titulo_pronto + '</h1>');
}; /*e o nome no topo da pagina */

document.title = "PVP - " + document.getElementById(titulo).innerText; /*coloque o nome do topo da gina como titulo do html */
```

```html
<h1 id="titulo">kauã</h1>
```

I expected these steps:

1. check if there's already a h1 with the id of "titulo"; if not then get the document name, remove the extension name and replace "_" with " " and add this to the `<h1 id="titulo">`. If yes, do nothing.
2. write the inner-text of `<h1 id="titulo">` in the `<title>` tag.

I got this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeZTf.png):

[image]

[The console says this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck7sT.png):

[image]

Comment: `document.getElementById(titulo)` does _not_ look for `id="titulo"`, but for whatever the _variable_ `titulo` stands for (which doesn't seem to be initialized yet). Did you mean: `document.getElementById("titulo")`?

Comment: @OskarGrosser so the "" will make the script look for the id intead of a variable?
i want to search by a h1 with the id titulo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have wrong condition in if statement. Change != to ==, surround id string inside getElementById with quotes and the error will be solved.

If you want, this is my quick refactor of your code.

```
(() => {
    document.write('<a href="rpg.html"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/U%2B2190.svg/25px-U%2B2190.svg.png"></a><br>');

    let headline = document.querySelector('#titulo');
    let title = '';

    if (!headline) {

        const url = window.location.pathname;
        const fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        
        title = fileName.replace(/\.\w+$/gi, '').replace('_', ' ');

        headline = document.createElement('h1');
        headline.textContent = title;
        document.body.appendChild(headline);

    } else
        title = headline.textContent;

    document.title = 'PVP - ' + title;
})();
```

Comment: this "solved" my problem,the h1 tags become dupped when the if is false because the script loads before the body,is there any way to automate the vs code to write a code like the html sample?

Comment: Place the JS before the closing `</body>` tag. Or if you have your JS in a js file, add a `defer` attribute to the script tag. `<script defer src="your.js"></script>` NOTE: Pay attention to `document.write()`. This will overwrite all the content of the page if it is run after the document is loaded. The `document.write()` should only be run while the page is rendering, not at the end.

Comment: About your question about VS Code, I can't help you. I use IntelliJ Webstorm.

Answer (score 0):

When looking for an element by ID, be sure to send it as a string:

```
document.write('<a href="rpg.html"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/U%2B2190.svg/25px-U%2B2190.svg.png"></a><br>');

/*se existir um não titulo... */
if (document.getElementById("titulo") != null )
{
  var nome_do_documento = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1); 

  /*colete o nome do documento */
  var titulo = nome_do_documento.replace('_',' ');

  /*troque _ por um espaço */
  var titulo_pronto = titulo.replace('.html','');

  /*apague a extenção do nome */
  document.write('<h1 id="titulo">'+ titulo_pronto +'</h1>');
};

/*e o nome no topo da pagina */
document.title = "PVP - " + document.getElementById("titulo").innerText;

/*coloque o nome do topo da gina como titulo do html */
```

In your example the quotes are missing, which is treated as a variable named `titulo` (likely to be `undefined` the first time `getElementById()` is called, then set to `nome_do_documento.replace('_',' ')` the second time).

Comment: i added the quotes but i'm still getting the same problem